# Parse missing ability to manage relationships in Data Explorer

Tags: parse-platform, relationship, rapid-prototyping

It's really frustrating that there is no ability to manage relations in Parse Data Explorer and from reading around this has been a requested feature found lacking by people for quite a while. Will this ever come from Parse or does anybody have any good tips on how to manage this?

Comment: What do you want to achieve ?? There are lots of things you can do in the dashboard

Comment: I want to be able to visually select and make relations to objects in other classes.

Comment: Click on any Relation and it will open a sub table showing you all the records in that Relation. To add an object, create a row in that sub table with the objectId of the object you want to add in that Relation

Comment: It's very clumsy and a pain to deal with if you want to use already created rows. I bought a Mac App to better deal with Parse Data called Appministrator and I am comfortable using that now.